# replace a line with lines based on information extracted from these line using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with following lines:

first pattern:

```
    .comm   "8"
    ....
    .comm   "20"
```

second pattern:

```
    .comm   _resultAvg,8,4
    .comm   _resultSwap,8,4
    .comm   _resultMax,20,4
```

I want to replace first pattern with:

```
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
    ...
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
```

And 2nd pattern as:

```
.data
_resultAvg:
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
.data
_resultSwap:
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
.data
_resultMax:
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
    .data.32 0
```

I can peform first task using;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use String::Interpolate;
my $j=0;

while (<>) {
    if (my ($string) = /^\s+\.comm\s+"(.*)"/) {
        for( $j=0; $j < ($string/4); $j = $j +1){
            print  "\t.data.32\t0\n";
        }
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```

How to perform second task? That is find the numeric e.g. 20 and divide it  by 4 and then put corresponding # of ".data.32 0" lines after starting with relevant symbol.

regards

Comment: Crossposted to https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1225199

Comment: There's no real difference between the two. You use the same approach for both. Grab the length, then loop length/4 times. Print `.data` and the symbol name before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modification to your code to handle the second case:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
    if (my ($string) = /^\s*\.comm\s+(.*)/) {
        my $cnt;
        if ($string =~ /^"(\d+)"$/) {
            $cnt = $1 / 4;
        } elsif ($string =~ /^(.+),(\d+),(\d+)$/) {
            print ".data\n$1:\n";
            $cnt = $2 / $3;
        } 
        for (1 .. $cnt){
            print  "\t.data.32\t0\n";
        }
    } else {
        print;
    }
}
```